# PHP get base64 decoding xml array and encode it to pdf

Tags: php, arrays, xml, pdf

I need to convert XML array (contained base64 decoding) and encode it to PDF.

This is the array:

```
<response>
<xmlArray>
<blabla>TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdC4gTnVuYyB2ZW5lbmF0aXMsIGp
1c3RvIHV0IGF1Y3RvciBzZW1wZXIsIHB1cnVzIGxlY3R1cyBlbGVtZW50dW0gbGliZXJvLCBhYyBwZWxsZW50ZXNxdWUgYW50ZSBqdXN0b
yBldCB0dXJwaXMuIE51bmMgYmliZW5kdW0gZWdlc3RhcyBkb2xvciB2b2x1dHBhdCBlZ2VzdGFzLiBTdXNwZW5kaXNzZSBkYXBpYnVzIHN
lbSBvZGlvLCBpbiBmYXVjaWJ1cyBsZWN0dXMgcHVsdmluYXIgdml0YWUuIE5hbSBtYXR0aXMgZXVpc21vZCBhdWd1ZSwgZWdldCBmaW5pY
nVzIGxlbyBoZW5kcmVyaXQgbmVjLiBDbGFzcyBhcHRlbnQgdGFjaXRpIHNvY2lvc3F1IGFkIGxpdG9yYSB0b3JxdWVudCBwZXIgY29udWJ
pYSBub3N0cmEsIHBlciBpbmNlcHRvcyBoaW1lbmFlb3MuIE51bmMgaWQgbnVuYyBsZWN0dXMuIFBlbGxlbnRlc3F1ZSBsYWN1cyB1cm5hL
CB2aXZlcnJhIGNvbnZhbGxpcyBlZmZpY2l0dXIgdmVsLCBhbGlxdWFtIHNpdCBhbWV0IGRpYW0uIEluIGEgYWxpcXVldCBtYXNzYS4gU2V
udCwgdGVtcHVzIGhlbmRyZXJpdCBlbmltIGZhdWNpYnVzLiBEb25lYyBtYXR0aXMgZWxpdCBub24gbWFzc2EgaW50ZXJkdW0gZmF1Y2lid
XMuIEFlbmVhbiBub24gbWF1cmlzIGluIHVybmEgbWFsZXN1YWRhIGx1Y3R1cy4=
</blabla>
</xmlArray>
</response>
```

My attempt up until now is

```
<?php 

// 1st. convert xml array; get the blabla array information

$blabla2 = $xml->xmlArray->blabla;

// remove CR, new lines and whitespace on blabla2

$blabla3 = str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $blabla2);


// 2nd. encode it to PDF

header('Content-type: application/pdf');

$blabla4 = base64_decode($blabla3 );

echo $blabla4 ;
?>
```

The result is a pdf, but not the way I expected as it shows this line on pdf:

`%PDF-1.410obj<</Title(þÿ)/Creator(þÿwkhtmltopdf0.12.2.4) ...`

Would you mind to tell me how to show the pdf properly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: using a PDF creation library, probably. Just setting the content type doesn't actually turn the document into a real PDF. You can set the content type to JPG and get the same result. The browser might be confused but the actual output will be identical.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm using cakephp with dompdf actually and that's the result. But turning to image sounds like an idea. I'll try.

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. PDF is perfectly fine it you can do it correctly. And what you've got now certainly won't become an image (in fact you'd be better to leave it as base64 to try and do that!). My example was meant to point out that content-type on its own is meaningless. You mention dompdf but I see no evidence of any PDF library interaction - you seem to be just echoing the decoded base64 content directly to the browser?

Comment: True that. I tried with pdf library on controller with decoding directly base64 but the xml output turn out always has CR in the beginning of the array. Already remove CR and even use trim method but it didn't work. All major browser cannot converted and only IE could translate and properly show the pdf. Really odd. That's why I use different approach, try to echoing to browser.

Comment: PDF is a binary file format with a specific way of storing the content. You need to use a library to input your human-readable text content (so decoding from base64 is the correct first step...

Comment: ...then next you presumably need to parse the resulting XML document and extract the right bits from it to put into the PDF) and then the library will output the binary data in the PDF format. Just echoing text to the browser gets you just that - text. If you tried to use a PDF library and failed then please post the code you wrote and explain the problem you're having with it. Getting that working is the only solution to your problem.

Comment: Ay thanks. I'm gonna try another approach based on your advice.